# What are the Docker RUN params for mimicking IronWorker memory constraints?

Tags: docker, iron.io, ironworker

In the past I've run into trouble when hosting my workers in a cloud infrastructure because of memory constraints that weren't faithfully reproduced when testing the code locally on my overpowered machine.

IronWorker is one such cloud provider that limits workers in its multi-tenant infrastructure to 380mb. Luckily with their switch to docker, I can hope to catch problems early on by asking my local docker container to use artificial memory limits when testing.

But I'm not sure as to which parameters from the following: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ are the right ones to use when setting a 380mb limit ... any advice?

Does the logic from https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/#_example_managing_the_memory_shares_of_a_container still apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `--memory`, for example, based on the [node README](https://github.com/iron-io/dockerworker/tree/master/node):

```
docker run --memory 380M --rm -e "PAYLOAD_FILE=hello.payload.json" -v "$PWD":/worker -w /worker iron/node node hello.js
```